# Using Page User Identity Name In Login Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authentication

I have a created a project in Visual Studio 2012 using the default template. I want each user to be able to login and be redirected to a different page. I have implemented code that works on the first user login. However if I log out, then login with a different user, that user doesn't get redirected. When I debug the app, on the second login it come up blank on the Username. I have put the code in page_load event, is there a better event or better way of implementing this code?

```
var Username = Page.User.Identity.Name;

if (Username == "You" || Username == "you")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/you.aspx");
}
else if (Username == "Me" || Username == "me")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/me.aspx");
}
else if (Username == "Them" || Username == "them")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Them.aspx");
}
```

I have also tried this code as well, however none of the users are redirected once they logged in. The it looks to me like the aspx part of the code isn't fired after or @ login:

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    protected void LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is redirect the user to their page
        switch (Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "me":
                Response.Redirect("~/me.aspx");
                break;
            case "you":
                Response.Redirect("~/you.aspx");
                break;
            case "them":
                Response.Redirect("~/them.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
    protected void Unnamed6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Aspx Code Here:

```
<%@ Page Title="Log in" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChoresLists.Account.Login" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
    </hgroup>
    <section id="loginForm">
        <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
        <asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIn="LoggedIn">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
                </p>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" OnClick="Unnamed6_Click" />
                </fieldset>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
        <p>
            <%--<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Register</asp:HyperLink>
            if you don't have an account.--%>
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="socialLoginForm">

        <%--<h2>Use another service to log in.</h2>
        <uc:OpenAuthProviders runat="server" ID="OpenAuthLogin" />--%>
        <asp:Image ID="LoginImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/102_0273.png" Width="450px" />
    </section>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'd just stick a Page.User.Identity.Name.toLower() on your assignment, then you only need to check if username = "you", etc

Comment: I'd just stick with String.Equals(Username, "You", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: @MikeyMouse I was just testing the code, I was am going to go back and add more validation and comparison. And I agree with your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I needed to do. I didn't need to change the login form at all. The only thing that I needed to do was comment out this line in Web.Config file:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/"/>
```

Now my logins work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey hey hey why you are using:

```
if (Username == "You" || Username == "you")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/you.aspx");
}
if (Username == "Me" || Username == "me")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/me.aspx");
}
if (Username == "Them" || Username == "them")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Them.aspx");
}
```

Instead of using:

```
if (Username == "You" || Username == "you")
{
   Response.Redirect("~/you.aspx");
}
else if (Username == "Me" || Username == "me")
{
   Response.Redirect("~/me.aspx");
}
else if (Username == "Them" || Username == "them")
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Them.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I need to update my question, I am using else if. That is what I get for typing in the code, and not just pasting it. But nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Since URLs in IIS are typically case-insensitive you can just use this:

Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}.aspx", Page.User.Identity.Name));

As for why the second login isn't redirecting, we would need more information as to your page life cycle and if you are doing something like if (Page.IsPostBack) checks.  Are you even hitting this code when your second user logs in?

You should probably be handling the LoggedIn event of the Login control rather than putting this in Page_Load.  Something like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggedIn="LoggedIn"></asp:Login>
```

Code:

```
protected void LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}.aspx", Page.User.Identity.Name));
}
```

Comment: Yes the code is hitting on each user, I don't see any post back on the page. However the login comes up empty of the second try.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this

Add a OnLoggedIn event to your asp:Login page

```
    <asp:Login  OnLoggedIn="LoggedOn" .../>
```

Then have a method like this

```
    protected void LoggedOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "you":
                Response.Redirect("~you.aspx");
                break;
            case "me":
                Response.Redirect("~me.aspx");
                break;
            case "them":
                Response.Redirect("~them.aspx");
                break;
            default:
                Response.Redirect("Somewhere.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what you saying is I should not use the page_load event, and create a method and put my code in the method. Then link the methoed to the OnLoggedIn in the login.aspx page?

Comment: Yeah, page load would be for things you want to happen each time the page loads (which includes someone clicking a button, or any kind of post back)
If you put that method in the code behind on your login page, it should be tidier

Comment: I tried the code that you posted but, now no users get redirected at all. I created a method out side the page load, in the code behind. Then I created the OnLoggedIn event in the login part of the login aspx page.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried it too. That method doesn't trigger. Looks like this guy has the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196915/login-controls-loggedin-event-not-firing
Something about the request getting sent to the return URL before the above event

Comment: I am looking in to the URL that you posted. Thanks for the link, I will let you know what happens.

Comment: I have looked into the URL. I am not sure that is going to work for me. I don't have custom login page, nor controls. They came with the project by default.